# Deducting from health

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have a hull and shield and I want when damaged to take the damage and deduct it from shield first and then when thats empty to take from hull. But if shield had 100 left and damage was 400 then the hull if started at 1000 would be 700.

Here what I managed to do, the shield part works but the hull algorithim is too difficult for me to grasp.

```
Player.prototype.deductHealth = function(damage)
{

  var shield = (this.PlayerShield - damage);
  var remainder = (damage - this.PlayerShield);
  var hull = this.PlayerHull;

  if(this.PlayerShield < 0)
   {

     hull = (this.PlayerHull - remainder);
   }

   if(hull <=0)
   {
   hull = 0;
   shield = 0;
   }

   this.PlayerHull = hull;
   this.PlayerShield = shield;

}
```

Comment: I think this question fits better on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: If you are modeling EVE, then note that any damage overage on the shields is ignored, except the bleed through which is skill and equipment dependent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't test it now, but something like this I think can work.

```
Player.prototype.deductHealth = function(damage)
    {

      var shield = (this.PlayerShield - damage);   
      var remainder = 0;
      if (shield<0) {
          remainder=-shield; 
          shield=0;
      }

      var hull = this.PlayerHull;        
      if(remainder > 0)
       {        
         hull = (this.PlayerHull - remainder);
       }

       if(hull <=0)
       {
          hull = 0;
          shield = 0;
       }

       this.PlayerHull = hull;
       this.PlayerShield = shield;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hm... try this, I think you are have problems because you're confusingly referencing your local vars that represent hull and shield strength, and your member vars that represent hull and shield. My suggestion is to use just the member vars like so :

```
Player.prototype.deductHealth = function(damage)
{

  var shieldOverkill = (damage - this.PlayerShield);
  this.PlayerShield = this.PlayerShield - damage;

  if ( shieldOverkill > 0 )
  {
      this.PlayerHull = this.PlayerHull - shieldOverkill;
  }

  if( this.PlayerHull < 0)
  {
      this.PlayerHull= 0;
  } 
  if ( this.PlayerShield < 0 )
  {
      this.PlayerShield = 0;
  }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

So let's walk through it step by step:

```
Player.protoype.deductHealth = function (damage) {
   this.PlayerShield -= damage; // First deduct the damage from the shields:
   if (this.PlayerShield < 0) { // If shields are negative
     // Take the damage not absorbed by shields from hull;
     this.PlayerHull += this.PlayerShield;  // note we use + since shields are negative
     this.PlayerShield = 0; // Set shields to 0
     if (this.PlayerHull < 0) { // If hull now negative
       this.PlayerHull = 0; // set to zero.
     }
   }
}
```

A more advance version, using more appropriate names :

```
Player.prototype.takeHit (damage) {
  if ((this.shields -= damage) < 0) { // Shields exhausted ?
    if ((this.hull += this.shields) < 0) { // Hull exhausted?
       this.hull = 0;
    } 
    this.shields = 0;
  }
}
```